# Managing Large Number Of javascript/css (RAILS 3)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

As you can tell I have a large number of stylesheets/javascripts (one of the stylesheets is dynamic and can't be cached into all.css)

Obviously I only need some of the stylesheets in some situations, but that doesn't bode well for caching into one stylesheet. What is the best way to go about this? (For example I don't need the report stylesheets or highcharts unless I am on a specific report that needs highcharts)

```
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag ['autocomplete.css', 'datepicker.css', 'web.css', 'common.css', 'home.css', 'course.css', 'admin.css'], :cache => true %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag [@current_client.name.downcase + '/' + @current_client.name.downcase + '.css'], :cache => false %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag ['jquery.js', 'class.js', 'jquery.extensions.js','nested_form.js','jquery.tablednd.js','jquery.autocomplete.js', 'date.js', 'datepicker.js', 'rails.js', 'common.js', 'navigation.js', 'patient_autocomplete.js', 'courses/course_request.js', 'course_steps/sort_course_steps.js', 'course_steps/next_step.js', 'enrollments/complete_course.js', 'flowplayer/flowplayer.js', 'flowplayer/playlist.js', 'course_steps/video.js', 'course_steps/presentation.js', 'highcharts.js', 'reports/course_assignment.js', 'reports/courses_allocated.js', 'reports/pie_chart.js'], :cache => true %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Package things common to all pages into a single stylesheet & Javascript with [Jammit](http://documentcloud.github.com/jammit/) or some other concatenated file, and put that in your main layout; Then add some yields in your layout too (as shown below). Then in your relevant views use content_for blocks (or helpers) to add in what you need.

```
# app/views/application.html.erb
<%= javascript_include_tag 'all_compacted.js' %>
<%= yield :extra_js %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'all_compacted.css' %>
<%= yield :extra_css %>

# random view that needs something not in all_compacted.js
<%= content_for :extra_js do %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'highcharts.js' %>
<% end %>
```

There is also the [Javascript_auto_include](https://github.com/kernow/javascript_auto_include) plugin, that will autoload JS files based on controller/action, but that's probably better suited to something with lots of custom javascript on every page (A situation *I'm* quite familiar with).

It might also be worth checking out [head.js](http://headjs.com/), to do non-blocking loading of javascripts.

Comment: It seems JavaScript_autoinclude is no longer maintained, any ideas?

Comment: No maintenance shouldn't turn you off to it, look through the code, its super simple. You could get practically the same effect by putting <body id="<%= params[:controller] %>"> and a little javascript to load the extra files like so: $.getScript('/public/'+$('body').attr('id')+'.js');